# Link a custom post type to its own page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a CPT called businesses and have created posts within that however, when I click on any of the posts, they show a blank page.  Anyone know why?

```
<?php
//create a custom post type for new businesses
function create_businesses() {
      $labels = array(
        'name'                  => 'Our Businiesses',
        'singular_name'         => 'Our Businesses',
        'add_new_item'          => 'Add A New Business', 'chandco',
        'new_item'              => 'New Business', 'chandco',
        'edit_item'             => 'Edit Business', 'chandco',
        'view_item'             => 'View Business', 'chandco',
        'all_items'             => 'All Businesses', 'chandco',
        'add_new'               => 'Add A New Business', 'chandco'
      );
      $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'businesses' ),
      );
    register_post_type( 'businesses', $args);
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_businesses' );
?>
```

Comment: Create single-businesses.php and regenerate your .htacess using permalink and paste sing.php's code into new created file and than check

Comment: @AkshayShah ive made a custom template though which has all my code in it

Comment: How u create custom template and did you check error.log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Wordpress standard, this output will handle by the "single.php" file ( Common file for all posts single view ).

But if you are getting blank page then you can try again by creating the specific file for the "businesses" custom post type posts.

Create a file called "single-businesses.php" file. So now if you click on any of the posts, Wordpress will call this specific file and generate the output.

Comment: this worked, thank you. would I need to keep this file in the themes root folder or can i put it in a folder ie. 'page-templates'?

Comment: It should be in your themes **root folder**.